# Excel VBA Conditionally Remove Duplicates By Lookup Value

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, conditional-statements

I wasn't quite sure how to title this question, but it's as concise as I could think of. Sorry if it's junk.

I have a list created on Sheet2 based on info from Sheet1. What I'd like to do is examine ColumnA and remove duplicate rows if the matching value on Sheet1 ColumnB's offset ColumnE doesn't equal "SUB-ASSY".

Basically:
Find the value from Sheet2, ColumnA on Sheet1, ColumnB.
Get the value from Sheet1, ColumnE
If it does NOT match "SUB-ASSY", delete any duplicates on Sheet2
This should leave one instance of all non-subassembly entries and leave subassemblies alone.

Does this make any sense?

I think I need to do some INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP, but I don't know if that'd be the right way to go (or exactly how I'd do it). Does anyone have a good way to do this?

I appreciate any help. I can include the workbook if needed, but it looks up a bunch of stuff on an sql server, so it might not work correctly if you can't connect.

Thanks Again,

-stu

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a general idea on how to do this, or a VBA macro?

One way I'm thinking that could get you going is in your second sheet (which, in the end, will have only unique entries) create a 'helper column'.  Let's say Column F is empty.  You can do a simple "if" statement that will check for the value on that row, in column A is in that other sheet.  If so, return "DUPLICATE" (or some note, "Duplicate, delete", etc.).  Then run that down the columns, then sort that whole table by your new column.  This will sort all the duplicate values in one big block, which you can highlight and delete.

It could help if you show a little bit of what the data looks like on your Sheet1 and Sheet2 (can be made up data, doesn't have to be SQL server info).

Comment: I'd like to work it in with the VBA macro that already runs if possible. I'd also like to avoid helper columns if I can, but if that's the only way...

[Here's a link to the workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24293397/Excel%20Example%2001.xls). I've just copied the values, so there's no data connecion, etc.

Comment: Sheet3 has the data that should be there after removing the duplicates.